# How can I create a dropdown menu in Flutter that can have a heading with a specified width and have menu options that are of the same width?

Tags: flutter, mobile, widget

I want to create a dropdown menu that can be opened by clicking anywhere on the row of the title. How can I make it so that the menu choices also span the same width as the parent or the heading of the menu? I have tried using MenuAnchor but don't know how to make the menuChildren span a specified width.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You can wrap it in a `ButtonTheme` and set `alignedDropdown` to true.

```
return Container(
  width: 300.0,
  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
    child: ButtonTheme(
      alignedDropdown: true, //<--- Here
      child: DropdownButton(
        value: name,
        items: listOfDropdownMenuItems,
        onChanged: onChanged,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

**2)** You can set `isExpanded` to true.

```
return Container(
  width: 300.0,
  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
    child: DropdownButton(
      isExpanded: true, //<--- Here
      value: name,
      items: listOfDropdownMenuItems,
      onChanged: onChanged,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: From these two methods you can give the same width

Comment: This does achieve the same width request I had, but how can I make it so the dropdown menu has a constant title or heading that is not replaced by the selected option? This might not be possible using the DropdownButton.